# The Laravel way of separating items in a collection based on user_id

Tags: laravel

In the Event-model I have this relationship:

```
public function eventQuestionUsers(){ 
  return $this->hasMany( 'App\EventQuestionUsers' );
}
```

So when I get an `$event` in my Controller, I do this:

```
public function show( $event_id ){
  $user = Auth::user();
  $event = Event::where( [ 'id', '=', $event_id ] )->get();

  if( $user->can( 'manage', $event ) ){
    $event->load( 'eventQuestionUsers' );
  }

  return view( single_event, [
    'event' => $event
  ]);
}
```

But now I'm I would like the collection to split-up the `eventQuestionUsers` based on the `user_id`. So that it would look like this:

```
$event = [
  'name' => 'Blah blah',
  'date' => '2021-09-18 20:30:00'
  'eventQuestionUsers' => [
    15 => [ // 15 is a user_id
      $eventQuestionUser,
      $eventQuestionUser,
    ],
    16 => [ // 16 is a user_id
      $eventQuestionUser,
      $eventQuestionUser,
      $eventQuestionUser,
      $eventQuestionUser,
    ],
    18 => [ // 18 is a user_id
      $eventQuestionUser,
      $eventQuestionUser,
    ],
  ]
```

---

### Solution attempt

Normally I would just make a public static helper-function, that takes `$eventQuestionUsers` and an input and returns what I want, by iterating over the whole this, like such:

```
public static function clusterEventQuestionUsersBasedOnUserId( $eventQuestionUsers ){
  $returned = [];
  foreach( $eventQuestionUsers as $eventQuestionUser ){
    $user_id = $eventQuestionUser->user_id;
    if( ! array_key_exists( $user_id, $returned ) ){
      $returned[ $user_id ] = [];
    }
    $returned[ $user_id ][] = $eventQuestionUser;
  }
  return $returned;
}
```

I wouldn't use a Collection, since that is immutable, so adding entries like seen above usually is a bit of a pain.

What is 'The Laravel Way' of doing this? Or does it sound fine? It feels very 'un-laravel' like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `$event->eventQuestionUsers` is a collection instance and this means you can use laravel collection methods directly on it and in this case, `groupBy()`. So

```
public function show( $event_id ){
  $user = Auth::user();
  $event = Event::where( [ 'id', '=', $event_id ] )->get();

  if( $user->can( 'manage', $event ) ){
    $event->load( 'eventQuestionUsers' );
    $event->eventQuestionUsers->groupBy('user_id');//the only new stuff
  }

  return view( single_event, [
    'event' => $event
  ]);
}
```

Comment: If I changed `$event->eventQuestionUsers->groupBy('user_id');` to `$event = $event->eventQuestionUsers->groupBy('user_id');` then it was what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure if i understood you correctly, but if you have the user_id in your relation, you can group by your lazy eager load like so

```
$event->load(['eventQuestionUsers' => function($query) {
    $query->groupBy('user_id');
}]);
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)